# Angular custom directive: performance consideration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement where, I have to benchmark the custom angular directives. Therefore, I need to know, what are the steps, a custom angular directive goes through, before getting added into the DOM? 
Suppose, I create a directive like the one given below

```
angular.module('Example', [])
.directive('sampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      title: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
      .....
      .....
    },
    templateUrl: 'sample.html'
  };
});
```

Does it have any performance impact with the usage of transclude and scope?
Let me know, if you want something specific to answer this question.

Comment: Custom directives use the same pipeline / flow of compilation/link that "built-in" directives, such as `ng-if`, `ng-model`, use.The only thing to pay attention to is unnecessary bindings. For example, `"="` binding is two-way, and many times two-way-ness is not necessary

Comment: one of them is don't use jQuery or don't touch DOM at all.

Comment: @YOU I am happy that I am not using any jQuery inside my directive. I am using angular's jqLite.